# Can features negatively correlated with the target be used?

Tags: feature-selection, correlation

In feature selection (for a regression problem), can features that are negatively correlated with the target variable be chosen to predict the target? 
I don't think negative correlation means the predictor does not provide any information about the target.

Some feature selection methods (like [Filter method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection#Filter_method)) are based on using only those predictors that have high correlation to the target variable, and dropping those with low correlation.

My question is - shouldn't negative correlated features also be considered? I think the problem of feature selection should be whether a feature is "simply correlate " with the target or not, rather than whether it is a Positive/Negative correlation. Am I right? Can someone please clear my confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, don't mistake a low correlation (absolute value close to 0) with a negative correlation.

A large negative correlation is just as useful as a large positive correlation. The only difference is that for a positive correlation, as the feature increases, the target will increase. For a negative correlation, as the feature decreases, the target will increase.

Any model you choose should be able to handle the correlation sign (+/-).

If you are looking at feature reduction, select features with a correlation close to 0. This means that the feature does not have a useful relationship to the target, and won't help with any prediction.

Answer (score 5):

Negative correlation is not the same as low correlation.
If variables $x$ and $y$ have a correlation value of $c$, then $-x$ and $y$ will have a correlation of $-c$.
When people talk about "low correlation" they usually mean correlation that is close to 0.

In the context of machine learning, negative correlation is just as good as positive correlation; do your filtering based on the absolute value of the correlation.